# Connection to Mongodb-Native-Driver in express.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, node-mongodb-native

I am using mongodb-native-driver in express.js app. I have around 6 collections in the database, so I have created 6 js files with each having a collection as a javascript object (e.g `function collection(){}`) and the prototypes functions handling all the manipulation on those collections. I thought this would be a good architecture.

But the problem I am having is **how to connect to the database? Should I create a connection in each of this files and use them?** I think that would be an overkill as the connect in mongodb-native-driver creates a pool of connections and having several of them would not be justified.

**So how do I create a single connection pool and use it in all the collections.js files?** I want to have the connection like its implemented in mongoose. Let me know if any of my thought process in architecture of the app is wrong.

*Using Mongoose would solve these problems, but I have read in several places thats it slower than native-driver and also I would prefer a schema-less models.*

**Edit:** I created a module out of models. Each collection was in a file and it took the database as an argument. Now in the index.js file I called the database connection and kept a variable db after I got the database from the connection. (*I used the auto-reconnect feature to make sure that the connection wasn't lost*). In the same index.js file I exported each of the collections like this

```
exports.model1 = require('./model1').(db)
exprorts.model2 = require('./model2').(db)
```

This ensured that the database part was handled in just one module and the app would just call function that each model.js file exported like `save()`, `fincdbyid()` etc (`whatever you do in the function is upto you to implement`).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**how to connect to the database?**

In order to connect using the MongoDB native driver you need to do something like the following:

```
var util = require('util');
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var client = mongodb.MongoClient;

var auth = {
    user: 'username',
    pass: 'password',
    host: 'hostname',
    port: 1337,
    name: 'databaseName'
};

var uri = util.format('mongodb://%s:%s@%s:%d/%s',
    auth.user, auth.pass, auth.host, auth.port, auth.name);

/** Connect to the Mongo database at the URI using the client */
client.connect(uri, { auto_reconnect: true }, function (err, database) {
    if (err) throw err;
    else if (!database) console.log('Unknown error connecting to database');
    else {

        console.log('Connected to MongoDB database server at:');
        console.log('\n\t%s\n', uri);

        // Create or access collections, etc here using the database object
    }
});
```

A basic connection is setup like this. This is all I can give you going on just the basic description of what you want. Post up some code you've got so far to get more specific help.

**Should I create a connection in each of this files and use them?**

No.

**So how do I create a single connection pool and use it in all the collections.js files?**

You can create a single file with code like the above, lets call it `dbmanager.js` connecting to the database. Export functions like `createUser`, `deleteUser`, etc. which operate on your database, then export functionality like so:

```
module.exports = {
    createUser: function () { ; },
    deleteUser: function () { ; }
};
```

which you could then `require` from another file like so:

```
var dbman = require('./dbmanager');

dbman.createUser(userData); // using connection established in `dbmanager.js`
```

**EDIT:** Because we're dealing with JavaScript and a single thread, the native driver indeed automatically handles connection pooling for you. You can look for this in the StackOverflow links below for more confirmation of this. The OP does state this in the question as well. This means that `client.connect` should be called *only once* by an instance of your server. After the `database` object is successfully retrieved from a call to `client.connect`, that `database` object should be reused throughout the entire instance of your app. This is easily accomplished by using the module pattern that Node.JS provides.

My suggestion is to create a module or set of modules which serves as a single point of contact for interacting with the database. In my apps I usually have a single module which depends on the native driver, calling `require('mongodb')`. All other modules in my app will not directly access the database, but instead all manipulations must be coordinated by this database module.

This encapsulates all of the code dealing with the native driver into a single module or set of modules. The OP seems to think there is a problem with the simple code example I've posted, describing a problem with a "single large closure" in my example. This is all pretty basic stuff, so I'm adding clarification as to the basic architecture at work here, but I still do not feel the need to change any code.

The OP also seems to think that multiple connections could possibly be made here. This is not possible with this setup. If you created a module like I suggest above then the first time `require('./dbmanager')` is called it will execute the code in the file `dbmanager.js` *and* return the `module.exports` object. The exports object is cached and is also returned on each subsequent call to `require('./dbmanager')`, however, the code in `dbmanager.js` will only be executed the first `require`.

If you don't want to create a module like this then the other option would be to export only the `database` passed to the callback for `client.connect` and use it directly in different places throughout your app. I recommend against this however, regardless of the OPs concerns.

Similar, possibly duplicate Stackoverflow questions, among others:

- [How to manage mongodb connections in nodejs webapp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14464750)
- [Node.JS and MongoDB, reusing the DB object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17099466/1359785)
- [Node.JS - What is the right way to deal with MongoDB connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680985/what-is-the-right-way-to-deal-with-mongodb-connections)

Comment: I have considered the solution you have given but didn't go ahead with it because as I stated above I have around 6 collections and the idea of having to write all the manipulations inside one single large closure. Secondly in your method there is a chance that more than one connection can be made as it doesn't check for already connected or not.

Comment: No matter how many times you `require(./dbmanager)' it will not call `client.connect` multiple times. The only 'chance' that more than one connection will be made is if you run multiple instances of the server. Node.JS will execute the code only the first time it is required, returning only the `exports` with each subsequent call.

Comment: The -1 is lacking in explanation. Contrary to your comment, you never mention anything about a single closure in your question. I specifically answer each of your questions: they were regarding whether you should create connections in multiple different files. I stand by my answer: it's not necessary.

Comment: Yeah I didn't mention it in the question but its not a good practice, and I do feel that writing explicitly about following good practice is not important. Edit your answer to avoid the problem and I may accept the answer also.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by editing my question to avoid the problem. You're vague on exactly what you think the problem is.. This is all pretty standard stuff. Please post an example if you have a way to improve my code, even in the smallest way. I would love to learn. You do not need to write "all the manipulations inside on single large closure". Your files in Node.JS are modules contained within a closure that spans the entire file. Each function created within it will also have its own closure.

Comment: Thanks for the declarative answer.....I really appreciate it. And is exactly the solution I had done myself. Sorry for the -1 I had given before but I have now reverted it to +1. I hope you do the same for the question too.

Comment: StackOverflow locks in votes after so long I cannot revert my score on my question until the question is edited. Add an edit to your question to try to explain how you resolved your problem and I will repeal my previous vote, I'm sure it could help with others as well.

Comment: @CoryGross Done accordingly

Comment: Your code is right, but the connection does established asynchronously. The best way to do this : http://blog.howarddierking.com/2014/07/01/managing-database-connection-in-expressjs.html

Answer (score 2):

As accepted answer says - you should create only one connection for all incoming requests and reuse it, but answer is missing solution, that will create and cache connection. I wrote express middleware to achieve this - [express-mongo-db](https://github.com/floatdrop/express-mongo-db). At first sight this task is trivial, and most people use this kind of code:

```
var db;
function createConnection(req, res, next) {
    if (db) { req.db = db; next(); }
    client.connect(uri, { auto_reconnect: true }, function (err, database) {
        req.db = db = databse;
        next();
    });
}

app.use(createConnection);
```

But this code lead you to connection-leak, when multiple request arrives at the same time, and `db` is undefined. `express-mongo-db` solving this by holding incoming clients and calling `connect` only once, when module is required (not when first request arrives).

Hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

I just thought I would add in my own method of MongoDB connection for others interested or having problems with different methods

This method assumes you don't need authentication(I use this on localhost)

Authentication is still easy to implement

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var Server      = require('mongodb').Server;

var client = new MongoClient(new Server('localhost',27017,{
                                socketOptions: {connectTimeoutMS: 500},
                                poolSize:5,
                                auto_reconnect:true
                            }, {
                                numberOfRetries:3,
                                retryMilliseconds: 500
                            }));

client.open(function(err, client) {
    if(err) {
        console.log("Connection Failed Via Client Object.");
    } else {
        var db = client.db("theDbName");
        if(db) {
            console.log("Connected Via Client Object . . .");
            db.logout(function(err,result) {
                if(!err) {
                    console.log("Logged out successfully");
                }
                client.close();
                console.log("Connection closed");
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Credit goes to Brad Davley which goes over this method in his [book](http://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/nodejs-mongodb-and/9780133844351/) (page 231-232)